# get posts by category or author wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get posts from a particular category or if the post by a particular user . It seems we could only have AND condition in wordpress . I know the below code is wrong but this is what I need to get - I want all the posts written by a particular user OR all the posts from a particular category

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 10,
    'offset'           => $PageStart,
    'query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR', /* <--                here */
    array(
        'author' => 18,
    ),
    array(
        'category' => 20,
        )
    ),
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',

);
//print_r($args);
$author_post = get_posts( $args );
```

Please do help. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to this ,I have done it with a custom query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT wposts.* 
            FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta 
                ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships 
                ON (wposts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy 
                ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
                  = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
                AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
                AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
                AND ( $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN($cat_list) 
                OR wposts.post_author IN ($authors) )
            ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
```

where $cat_list is an array with your category ids and $authors is an array with your author ids . Hope this would help someone in need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 10,
    'offset'           => $PageStart,
    'author'       => '18',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',

);
$author_post = get_posts( $args );

$args = array(

    'posts_per_page'   => 10,
    'offset'           => $PageStart,
    'category'         => '20',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
);
$category_post = get_posts( $args );
$total_post = array_merge($category_post,$author_post)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both do `get_posts()` 2 times.

1. all posts from user
2. all posts from the category
   and then merge both arrays with `array_merge()`

Comment: I have tried it ,but it makes a problem with pagination And i need the posts to be displayed in descending order , So if I could do it with a single query all these problems will be solved.